# What's the best way to read another process keystrokes?

Tags: c#, windows

I've managed to send to another process window keystrokes using Windows API (user32.dll, SendMessage, PostMessage). Now, I'd like to read keystrokes, should I use win API again? I've found GetMessage method but I've also read, that it can't be used to read other's process messages.

Comment: I believe the search phrase you are looking for is `keyboard hook`.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can implement keyboard hooks as managed code, and if you can, why you would want to. Also, be aware that merely calling keyboard hook functions will get your app flagged as malware by most anti-virus software.

Comment: Do a Google search for "C# keylogger". (I did implement, and modify, one of them a couple of years ago, but can't remember which one right now, and that machine is powered down.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` to create a system-wide hook that can catch keyboard input messages.